# v-model doesn't recognize the property passed if textarea is empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to do a very simple chat app. One of the components that control the submission of one message after "enter" is giving me this error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"
```

found in

```
---> <MessagesComponent> at resources/js/components/MessagesComponent.vue
   <Messagerie> at resources/js/components/MessagerieComponent.vue
     <Root>"
```

However, if I predefine the 'content' property in the data function as something like 'text123' it works perfectly without any errors, but it shows this message on the input field (textarea) which of course is not desirable. I had verified the code many times and I don't really know where the error could be. Can someone give an idea?

```
<template>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">john</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <Message :message="message" v-for="message in messages" :user="user"/>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="content" v-model="content" placeholder="Écrivez votre message" :class="{'form-control': true, 'is-invalide': errors['content']}" @keypress.enter="sendMessage"></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors['content']">
                    {{ errors['content'].join(', ') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import Message from './MessageComponent'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
    components: {Message},
    data(){
        return {
            content: '',
            errors: {},
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['user']),
        messages: function(){
            return this.$store.getters.messages(this.$route.params.id)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadMessages()
    },
    watch: {
        '$route.params.id': function(){
            this.loadMessages()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadMessages(){
            this.$store.dispatch('loadMessages', this.$route.params.id)
        },
        async sendMessage(e){
            if(e.shiftKey === false){
                this.errors = {}
                e.preventDefault()          
                try{
                    await this.$store.dispatch('sendMessage', {
                        content: this.content,
                        userId: this.$route.params.id
                    })
                }catch (e){
                    this.errors = e.errors
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it falling into the `catch`? `this.errors = e.errors` looks like a potential candidate for your problem.

Comment: yes it goes to the catch

Comment: So what is the value of `e.errors`? Try logging it out...

Comment: the value is 'undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that this line sets `this.errors` to `undefined`:

```js
this.errors = e.errors
```

In your template you're then trying to access `errors['content']`, which will fail. You can't access a property of `undefined`.

I'm not exactly sure what that line is trying to achieve, perhaps `e.errors` is not the correct property? The key thing is that you have to ensure that `this.errors` remains an object. e.g.

```js
this.errors = e.errors || {}
```

This will make the console error go away but to fix it properly would require some understanding of exactly what the value should be when `e.errors` is `undefined`.

Incidentally, there's no need to write `errors['content']` in your template. You can just use `errors.content`.

Comment: It does what you say, it makes the error dissapear, however it is not the expected result. The reason it should give an error in this case is because I dont want people doing enter and something being registered in the conversation

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo Sure. You've just got to populate `errors` appropriately to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes from errors, try to change errors for an array `errors: [],` in case that doesn't work try adding a condition for errors before every condition of errors for example `v-if="errors && errors['content']"`

Comment: I change this in my code and doesnt work, same error

Comment: remember that you have that to in your class `:class="{'form-control': true, 'is-invalide': errors['content']}"`  so you have to change it to  `:class="{'form-control': true, 'is-invalide': errors && errors['content']}"`

Comment: This works exactly like skirtle's answer. Still I would like to show the error. Because it is set to a minimum of 4 characters

Comment: ok, but this is other problem, as @skirtle says in his comment you have to populate errors appropriately, so, to make this happen, you have to get the errors from the backend, so, print e.errors in the catch, when you have an error and  please tell me what are you getting, so I can help you. and by the way are you using laravel?

Comment: Yes, it is laravel. When printing the error in the catch it gives undefined

Comment: yeah, then you can do something like this `<div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors && errors.content">
                    <span class="small text-danger" v-for="error in errors.content" >{{error}}</span>
                </div>` since laravel  validatore return an array with arrays of kind of errors. but be sure you are returning the errors in the backend with $validator->messages() for example.

Comment: I'll try this later I and will get back to you.

Comment: I decided to use another approach